# Dialog getWidth and getHeight return no integers no matter what

Tags: java, android, dialog, paint

I have implemented everything I can find here on StackOverflow. Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
        statusDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        statusDialog.show();
        final LinearLayout drawbar = (LinearLayout) statusDialog.findViewById(R.id.drawbar);
        int barWidth = drawbar.getWidth();
        int barHeight = drawbar.getHeight();
        DrawBar(drawbar);
}   

public void DrawBar(View v){
        LinearLayout statusDialog = (LinearLayout) v;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg);
        View bar = statusDialog.findViewById(R.id.drawbar);
        LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) statusDialog.findViewById(R.id.drawbar);
        int barWidth2 = statusDialog.getLayoutParams().width;
        int barHeight2 = statusDialog.getLayoutParams().height;
        int barWidth3 = v.getLayoutParams().width;
        int barHeight3 = v.getLayoutParams().height;
        int barWidth4 = bar.getLayoutParams().width;
        int barHeight4 = bar.getLayoutParams().height;
        int barWidth5 = v.getMeasuredWidth();
        int barHeight5 = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        int barWidth6 = statusDialog.getWidth();
        int barHeight6 = statusDialog.getHeight();
        test.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
        int barheight7 = test.getMeasuredHeight();
        int barwidth7 = test.getMeasuredWidth();
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);
        //canvas.drawRect(0, 0, barWidth, barHeight, paint);
        statusDialog.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), bg));
    }
```

drawbar.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

The statusDialog.show function works fine and shows the dialog that it should. I am trying to paint a bar to the screen that fills content horizontally in the layout I'm specifying here, after the layout is drawn to the screen. If I hard-code the layout height to [N]dp, I get a pixel count back, but otherwise everything just returns -1 and I'm not able to dynamically fill the last commented out line with `canvas.drawRect(0, 0, barWidth, barHeight, paint);`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. HALP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure of the real answer here, but I figured out that my problem was completely irrelevant and caused by my own ignorance/expected behavior.

The 480x800 (or whatever size) bitmap is automatically scaled into the FILL_PARENT View I was adding it to. So essentially I wasted 2 days on a problem that didn't matter, as I was trying to calculate the width of a progress bar wrapper. tl;dr, only getting return integers of -1 on measured views that fill or match parent seems to be normal.

themoreyouknow.gif